# Nested list / SortOrder for Pattern Comprehension List

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j: What is proper syntax to nest and sort order List Comprehension Results?

My record has media nodes, each linked to users that altered the media. I am trying to gather all the information about my record.

Simple list comprehension works great:

```
MATCH r
RETURN r {.*, Media: [(r)-[:HAS_MEDIA]->(m:Media) | m {.URL, .Type, .Order}]}
```

Here are my questions:

1) if there are many media, how can I sort m list by .Order?

2) I also want to gather information about m, available through other nodes. So I tried nesting:

```
MATCH r
RETURN r {.*, Media: [(r)-[:HAS_MEDIA]->(m:Media) | m {.URL, .Type, .Order,  [(m:Media-[t:MODIFIED_BY]->(u) | u.UserID] }]}
```

This throws a syntax error at the first nested bracket. Can it be done?

Ideally I'd like to collect more than u.UserID, including a t relationship property .DT.

3) When/if I get that working, same question as 1) - how can I sort u list by .DT?

Would be most grateful for any pointers!

--------- UPDATE After answer from cybersam:
YES! I need to add the new property names, as cybersam indicated. Thank you!

```
 MATCH (r)
 RETURN r {.*, Media: [(r)-[:HAS_MEDIA]->(m:Media) | m {.URL, .Type, .Order,  UserID: [(m)-[:MODIFIED_BY]->(u) | u.UserID] }]} 

MATCH (r)
RETURN r {.*, Media: [(r)-[:HAS_MEDIA]->(m:Media) | m {.URL, .Type, .Order,  UserID: [(m)-[t:MODIFIED_BY]->(u) | u {.UserID, DT: t.DT}] }]}
```

I need to study the order call a bit more, but I do not believe ORDER BY r.Order at very end will work. I am returning just one r node. Within that r array I want sort the subkeys (so Media by .Order and User by t.DT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (r)
RETURN r {
  .*, Media: [(r)-[:HAS_MEDIA]->(m:Media) |
  m {.URL, .Type, .Order,  UserID: [(m)-[:MODIFIED_BY]->(u) | u.UserID] }]}
ORDER BY r.Order;
```

In a map projection, every property needs a name, so I used `UserID` as the name of the inner pattern comprehension's result.

[UPDATED]

The query below may solve your updated question. The syntax for map projections and pattern comprehensions do not support sorting of contained lists.

```
MATCH (r)-[:HAS_MEDIA]->(m:Media)
WITH r, m ORDER BY m.Order
MATCH (m)-[t:MODIFIED_BY]->(u)
WITH r, m, u{.UserID, DT: t.DT} ORDER BY u.DT
WITH r, m{.URL, .Type, .Order, User: COLLECT(u)}
RETURN r {.*, Media: COLLECT(m)}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will respond in my original question because this field is limiting my response.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that sorting contained list isn't supported yet for pattern comprehension. Given x different node labels to go through it gets extremely clunky to write out all the sequential queries for each one. For those that don't need a particular sort order for collection, I can sort my array after collecting it. Thank you for your help!